# The story with Index Controllers, Views, Templates?

Tags: ember.js

I've created the following route in Ember:

```
this.resource('password_reset', { path: '/password_reset' }, function() {
    this.route("request");
    this.route("claim");
});
```

The Ember debugger -- which I LOVE btw -- shows me this results in the following:

[image]

I have created two templates so far:

1. /templates/password_reset.hbs
2. /templates/password_reset/index.hbs

When I go to the URL `http://my.server.com/#/password_reset` I would expect that -- based on what the debugger's telling me -- that the 2nd template listed (aka, `password_reset/index`) above is used but in fact it uses the frist one. What doing? Anyone care to shed some light on this mystery?

Comment: do you have an `{{outlet}}` defined in your `password_reset.hbs`?

Comment: ha. I do now. see my answer below. thanks.

Comment: yeah exactly, as stated in the docs: *Visiting /posts is slightly different. It will first render the posts template. Then, it will render the posts/index template into the posts template's outlet.*

Comment: yeah, i feel sufficiently dumb. it was a RTFM moment ... and I responded with a question. Oh well.

Comment: haha *RTFM moment* :) at this point you should accept your own answer although it will not give you any reputation :) It deserves an upvote for finally RTFM

Comment: yes i will ... i have to wait 2 days before i'm allowed to though. plenty of time to read. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think it can be chalked up to a newbie question. The relationship between these two controllers/views/templates becomes far more clear when I put an {{outlet}} into the /password_reset template. Then I can see that the password_reset/index shows up as the outlet. The index, in effect, becomes the default outlet when a sub-route is not defined. Pretty basic but somehow I didn't get it until I bumped into a wall or two.